# Regex to remove -001 from test-image-001.png but not when it has copy in front

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I am creating a bash script to mass rename images. Currently I use awk:

`$(echo ${file}| awk '{gsub(/\-00[0-9].png/,"")}1')`

When perfectly renames `test-image-001.png` to `test-image.png`

However I noticed that it also replaces `test-image-copy-001.png`. When the word `copy-` is in front it should leave the `-001.png` in place.

I tried to workout the exclusive operator like:

`\-00[0-9][^copy\-00].png`

But it doesn't work. Any thoughts on how to achieve the above in awk regex?

Comment: What should be the output for `test-image-copy-001.png`? should it not be changed?

Comment: Look up regex rules, `[]` is a character class, you can't match full words in it.

Comment: @inian exactly it should not replace anything

Comment: Does it have to be in awk? I think perl is better suited to this.

Comment: @123 it doesn't have to be awk but needs to work in bash, the output needs to be stored in a variable.

Comment: @osi Why does it need to be stored in a var? Have you considered the `rename` utility?

Comment: @123 because it is to compose a filename for other operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an external tool or regex for that. Bash can handle all these operations:

```
files=( test-image-001.png test-image-copy-001.png )

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ $file = *copy-00[[:digit:]]* ]]; then
        newfile=$file
    else
        newfile=${file/-00[[:digit:]]} # or newfile=${file/-00[0-9]}
    fi
    echo "$file -> $newfile"
done
```

Output is:

```
test-image-001.png -> test-image.png
test-image-copy-001.png -> test-image-copy-001.png
```

Comment: What it copy appears somewhere else in the string?